# @MappedSuperclass vs plain abstract class

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have created a base class for several entities that share the same properties, and I thought that it was a good use case for a `@MappedSuperclass`:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Invoiceable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="invoiceId", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * @var Invoice|null
     */
    protected $invoice = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CreditNote")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="creditNoteId", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * @var CreditNote|null
     */
    protected $creditNote = null;
}
```

However, I was surprised that when removing the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation, it still works as expected.

What is the purpose of `@MappedSuperclass` superclass then, if it works without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy [Marco Pivetta on the doctrine-user mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/_pDgQg87uGs/QZ1wqTcbqWAJ):

> This is really just a lucky case based on how the annotation driver works - agreed, it is confusing. It works because your properties are `protected`.
>
> I suggest you to try the same with XML or YAML mappings - you will see how it crashes badly.
>
> **You should still define that as a mapped superclass.**